# scroll down and scroll up event functions

Tags: jquery

I'm doing the following jquery for learning purpose. I wanted to increase the blue div width when scroll down and decrease when scroll up. Please suggest me where I'm doing wrong.

jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var last_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var current_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var changes_scroll = (current_scroll - last_scroll);


if (changes_scroll > 0) {
    $("#slide").width('+=10%');
} else {
     $("#slide").width('-=10%');
}

});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dRT8f/)

Answer (score 3):

```
var last_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
$(window).scroll(function () {

    var current_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var changes_scroll = (current_scroll - last_scroll);


if (changes_scroll > 0) {
    $("#slide").width('+=10%');
} else {
     $("#slide").width('-=10%');
}
 last_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

});
```

**[see DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/dRT8f/1/)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When scroll down it is increasing + + but I want to stop increasing the width when achieving 100%. how could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
var last_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
var current_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
```

If last_scroll and current_scroll are getting the same value assigned, `changes_scroll` will allways be zero